# Mongoose Populate Virtual Option Count returns whole document's count

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The mongoose populate virtual count is supposed to return the total number of documents that satisfies the ref, localField and foreignField. But when I use it, it returns the total number of documents ignoring the ref, localField and foreignField.

I used it without the count option and it rightly returned the number of documents satisfying the ref, localField and foreignField. 
But when I include count it returns the total number of documents ignoring them.

```
AuthorSchema.virtual('books', {
  ref: 'books',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'author_id'
});
```

returns 
    books_count: [
     {
      name: "Fox's dream",
      date: "2019-01-13T00:44:22.564Z"
     }
    ]

but

```
AuthorSchema.virtual('books_count', {
 ref: 'books',
 localField: '_id',
 foreignField: 'author_id'
});
```

returns 4 that is the total number of books collection

But I am expecting 1 because 1 satisfies the ref, localField and foreignField

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of mongoose (ref. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#count)
You should add count: true to options, which makes your code like this:

```
AuthorSchema.virtual('books', {
  ref: 'books',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'author_id',
  count: true
});
```